# Подскажите как разверстать лучше

Tags: css3, html, css

[image]
 - вот есть такой элемент. Нужно его разверстать так чтобы все надписи нажимались. и стрелочка нажималась... Никак не могу придумать как повесить эту прозрачность поверх ссылки чтобы ссылка была активная... :(

Comment: Вам нужно кроссбраузерное решение?

Comment: Ну само собой!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте полупрозрачный *png* или *gif* и сделайте его фоном в псевдоэлементе *:after*.

```
#tags {
  position: relative
}
#tags:after {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; right: 0
  width: 50px; height: 50px; 
  background-image: url('background.png'); 
}
```

Comment: Что-то не совсем разобрался... :after - работает со свойством content. А мне собственно текст добавлять не надо... Можете как-то подробнее описать? Да и ссылка не будет работать если она находится под бекграундом...

Comment: Дополнил ответ примером. Возможно, потребуется еще добавить z-index,  bakground-repeat и bakground-size - но это уже на ваше усмотрение. Последняя ссылка перекрывается только частично, поэтому должна работать.

Comment: Да я просто hover ом убираю при наведение это затемнение... и всё работает спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

градиент для текста
http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/js/gradient-text/
попробуйте может поможет, без костылей тут никак.

Comment: Спасибо - вариант хороший... Но как-то неохото для подобной мелочи JS плагин использовать... Но собственно я попробовал с :after - просто при наведение на поле к которому прикреплено :after - делаю 

.block_tag:hover span:after { display:none; } - и тогда при наведении текст фон пропадает и текст нажимается...

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://cssdesk.com/NHVdN)

```
.translucent:before {
  /* задает пустой блочный элемент 200x100 */
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;

  /* для того, что бы оверлей был точно над основным элементов */
  position: absolute;

  /* позволяет игнорировать события мышки */
  pointer-events: none;

  /* полупрозрачный градиент от #00ffffff до #ffffffff; */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );  
}
```

Однако, свойство `pointer-events: none;`, которое позволяет пропускать события типа click, [не работает в IE и Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events). Другой вариант пропускать события - это явно вешать обработчик на оверлей и уже в нем эмулировать клики по элементам.

Необходимый градиент можно сгенерировать одним из многочисленных онлайн генераторов. Например, [этим](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).